# How to anchor an element to the left side of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with two elements, a header and a footer.

```css
html,
body,
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #888;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
}

footer {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 80%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header></header>
  <footer></footer>
</main>
```

Please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bypMgJ) for a live example.

---

When I scroll the window horizontally, I need the header to always be centered in the middle of the screen.

I can’t use `position: fixed` because I need this element to be in the page flow.

`position: sticky` does exactly what I need, but unfortunately I can’t use it because the parent element’s width is the same as the viewport width. If I set the parent width to a width that is bigger than the viewport itself, I achieve what I want, but I’m hoping for a better solution.

I’d prefer a CSS-only solution but I’m open to a JS solution.

---

One of the many things I’ve tried so far is listening for the scroll event and adding a margin left to the element equal to `window.scrollX`, the idea being that it would stay anchored to the left edge of the window. However that doesn’t actually work, I’m not sure why.

In the example, if you try to set `position: sticky; left: 0;` in the header, then give a `width: 10000px;` to the main element, you’ll see my desired layout.

Is it possible to achieve this same layout, but without having to set a width?

Comment: [mcve] in your question please

Comment: I added the CSS and a codepen, I hope it’s clear enough now

Comment: ```header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  float-left: auto;
  float-right: auto;
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the footer need to have a hardcoded `width`? That seems to be where you'll have the most issues. If you simply have content in the footer that needs to be displayed and may be wider than the header, then I would recommend utilizing a solution like the following:

```css
html, body, main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #888;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1);
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 80%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
}

h1 {
margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <footer>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I want, now the problem I have is, when adding `overflow-x: scroll` to the footer, that actually breaks some position sticky trickery I have in there. It’s a very complicated layout. Anyway, thanks! I’ll accept your answer, though I may have to resort to JS at this point, at least for my use case. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Change the header css to this

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  float-left: auto;
  float-right: auto;
}
```

`Fixed` elements are relative to the html document and not the parent container, and aren't affected by scrolling. `Float left and right auto` center it on the page.

If you want the `footer` to go over the `header` on vertical scroll you should use `z-index` property.

```
footer {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 80%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1
}
```

Also you can fiddle between `fixed` and `absolute` absolute is relative to the parent container unlike `fixed`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can’t use `position: fixed` because when I scroll vertically I need the footer to go over the header

Comment: Thanks, your solution makes sense to me. The only problem is, I can’t use `position: fixed` on the footer either, because the footer has some content that is supposed to be navigated by scrolling the page horizontally. Sorry for not having been clear enough in my question...

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of writing javascript function that will handle the `marginLeft` value of the header was correct. 
I dont know why it did not work for you because you did not showed us your JS code, but here one way to achieve that:

[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=fa55f307-a899-4c13-9114-280dd04afedb)

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var left = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
    document.getElementById("myheader").style.marginLeft = left.toString() + "px";
  }, false);
</script>
```